# For Each Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button

I have a problem when I'm using the `For Each` loop:

If I Run this loop, I can see all (let's suppose) 100 controls.

```
For each Btn as Control in Controls
   If TypeOf Btn Is Button then
      If instr(1,Btn.Name,"Test",0) Then Debug.Print(Btn.name)
   End If   
Next
```

But if I need to delete them, the loop seems confusing looping through the controls and it skips some...

```
For each Btn as Control in Controls
   If TypeOf Btn Is Button then
      If instr(1,Btn.Name,"Test",0) Then Controls.Remove(Btn)
   End If   
Next
```

I tried to restart the loop each time I remove a control, but the solution is not so... elegant.

Is there anyway to fix this problem ?

Comment: `For each Btn as Control in Controls.ToList()`

Comment: You can't remove items from a list while enumerating it.  You need to either create another list and enumerate that while removing from the origjanl list, as @GSerg demonstrates, or else use a `For` loop and loop backwards, so that removing an item doesn't affect the indexes of the remaining items.

Comment: Also, if you only want `Buttons` then do this: `Controls.OfType(Of Button)().ToList()`.  If you only want `Buttons` whose names start with "Test" then do this: `Controls.OfType(Of Button)().Where(Function(b) b.Name.StartsWith("Test")).ToList()`.

Comment: Finally, unless you intend to use them again, you should be disposing those `Buttons`.  Disposing a control automatically removes it from its parent, so you simply need to call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```vb
For i As Integer = Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If TypeOf Controls(i) Is Button AndAlso Controls(i).Name.StartsWith("Test") Then
        Controls.RemoveAt(i) ' or Controls(i).Dispose()
    End If
Next
```

... or

```vb
For Each c In Controls.OfType(Of Button).
    Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("Test")).ToList
    Controls.Remove(c) 'Or c.Dispose()
Next
```

... or

```vb
For Each c In Controls.OfType(Of Button).
    Where(Function(x) x.Name.StartsWith("Test")).Reverse()
    Controls.Remove(c) 'Or c.Dispose()
Next
```

... to remove an object while *looping* it's collection.